# Round up an integer to multiple of 3

Tags: swift, integer, rounding

I would like to round an integer up to its closest multiple of 3. 
Example:

```
var numberOne = 2
var numberTwo = 7
```

- numberOne rounded up would equal 3
- numberTwo rounded up would equal 9

**I do not want it to ever round down.**

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this working in a Playground:

```
import Foundation

func roundToThree(value: Int) -> Int{
    var fractionNum = Double(value) / 3.0
    let roundedNum = Int(ceil(fractionNum))
    return roundedNum * 3
}

roundToThree(2)
roundToThree(7)
```

Answer (score 17):

My 2 ct:

```
func roundUp(value: Int, divisor: Int) -> Int {
    let rem = value % divisor
    return rem == 0 ? value : value + divisor - rem
}
```

Comment: Smartest, fastest and simplest

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it this way:

```
func roundUp(value: Int, divisor: Int) -> Int {
    let modulo = value % divisor
    var multiplier = value / divisor
    if modulo > 0 {
        ++multiplier
    }
    return divisor * multiplier
}
```

The function calculates:

- modulo: the modulo of the division of the value by the divisor
- multiplier: the integer division of the value by the divisor
- if modulo is greater than zero, the multiplier is incremented
- the resulting value is the divisor multiplied by the multiplier

Using integers only, this algorithm should be faster than any other based on floating point calculations.

I made the divisor a parameter, you can optionally decide to remove it and replace it in teh function body with the `3` literal, or assign it a default value:

```
func roundUp(value: Int, divisor: Int = 3) -> Int
```

Comment: Sometimes fingers live of their own life, doing auto corrections in the background. And yes, that was supposed to be `modulo`, but fingers know more about `modules`. Names fixed, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A swift3 Float extension with a configurable multiplier (adapted from the accepted answer from @erdekhayser)

```
extension Float {
    func roundUpTo(multiplier: Int) -> Int{
        let fractionNum = self / Float(multiplier)
        return Int(ceil(fractionNum)) * multiplier
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like Martin R's answer but works by rounding to the nearest multiple and not just by rounding up

**Swift 3/4**

```
func roundUp(value: Double, divisor: Double) -> Double {
    let rem = value.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: divisor)
    if(rem >= divisor / 2)
    {
        return rem == 0 ? value : value + divisor - rem
    }
    else
    {
        return rem == 0 ? value : value - rem
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin's code also rounds to nearest multiple. If you change type to `Int`, compiler is likely to generate same code.